# Can "mon bon" refer only to "my friend," or could it mean "my muse" or "my angel"?

Tags: expressions

Need to understand if phrase "mon bon" means "mon bon ami" or can suggest other meanings such as "muse" or "guardian angel."

Comment: I think we need the complete sentence.

Answer (score 3):

I think *mon bon* is more like *my friend*, but with quite a bit of condescension. It is quite dated too. I don't think anybody uses that today, unless there is a resurgence in popular speech.